# Вывод результата в консоль

Tags: java

Вопрос с отображением информации в консоль, так как на видеоуроках ютуба я встречаю, что такая
форма ввода предоставляет лектору читабельную инфу конструктора, у меня же - {1=Student@6d03e736}.
Пожалуйста, казалось такая банальная вещь, но я вообще не могу понять в чем дело.

Пример :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student st1 = new Student("Jhon","Konor",1);
       HashMap<Integer,Student> map = new HashMap<>();
       map.put(1,st1);
       System.out.println(map);
        }
    }
class Student {
    String name;
    String surname;
    Integer course;

    public Student(String getName, String getSurname, int getCourse){
        this.name= getName;
        this.surname = getSurname;
        this.course = getCourse;

    }
    public Student(int getCourse){
        this.course = getCourse;
    }
}
```

Output:

{1=Student@6d03e736}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не переопределили метод toString() в классе Student

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все заработало!

Comment: Ещё хочу добавить несколько замечаний по коду, модификатор доступа public не принято указывать в конструкторах, конструкторы всегда public по умолчанию, и не стоит добавлять get  в имена параметров это не отражает их судь и вводит в заблуждение, getXxx() используется в названии методов геттеров

Comment: @tka, только _неявный_ конструктор (без параметров) является публичным по умолчанию.  В данном случае определены несколько конструкторов и если не указать `public`, доступ к ним будет возможен только в пределах данного пакета (package private)